# Logistic regression with two binary categorical variables

Tags: r, binary, regression, modeling

I'm trying to model a logistic regression between two variables.
The target variable is called "revenue" and it's a binary variable where "yes" means that it did occur a transaction and "no" means it didn't.
The predictor I'm using is a variable called "Weekend" which is binary as well where "true" means that the transaction has been made on weekends and "false" means it didn't.
This is the procedure I'm following:

```
glm.fit1=glm(default~balance, family=binomial, data=Default) 
glm.probs1=predict.glm(glm.fit1,type="response")
glm.pred1=rep("No",N)
glm.pred1[glm.probs1>.5]="Yes"
table(glm.pred1,Default$default) 
confMat1<-addmargins(table(glm.pred1,Default$default))
confMat1 
delta1=(confMat1[1,2]+confMat1[2,1])/N*100 # misclassification error rate
delta1
```

The problem is that the output of the confusion matrix is the following one:

```
glm.pred1 FALSE TRUE  Sum
      No   6253 1144 7397
      Sum  6253 1144 7397
```

As you can see there is no row for "yes". So the error rate delta1 will be 100% (all the predictions are wrong /misclassified).
So I was wondering if there was a problem with the code / the procedure or if the predictor is simply that bad to make "accurate" predictions.
The output of the glm shows that the residual deviance has a tiny decrease compared to the null deviance, so it may be that the predictor is not useful at all (p value really low by the way).
Any hints ?

here's a quick look at the database:

```
> head(online_shoppers_intention_train)
# A tibble: 6 x 19
     X1 Administrative Administrative_~ Informational Informational_D~ ProductRelated ProductRelated_~ BounceRates ExitRates PageValues
  <dbl>          <dbl>            <dbl>         <dbl>            <dbl>          <dbl>            <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
1  9617              5             408.             2             47.5             54            1547.      0        0.0173        0   
2 12179             26            1562.             9            504.             183            9676.      0.0111   0.0142       19.6 
3  9905              4              58              2             28.5             82            4729.      0        0.0145        9.06
4  5745              3             103.             0              0               25            1109.      0        0.00167      61.3 
5 10067              7             165.             1             28.5            115            3428.      0        0.0163        4.97
6  7670             16             382.             3            199.              86            1618.      0.0151   0.0220        3.89
# ... with 9 more variables: SpecialDay <dbl>, Month <chr>, OperatingSystems <dbl>, Browser <dbl>, Region <dbl>, TrafficType <dbl>,
#   VisitorType <chr>, Weekend <lgl>, Revenue <lgl>
```

Comment: Can you add a reproducible sample dput(head(Default)) ?

Comment: I have added head(databse) to the original post, I don't know if it is what you were looking for.

Comment: The variables, default and balance are not there in this data.